# ¿Cómo hacer para enviar correctamente un array de JS a PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un array en Javascript, que se genera en la siguiente funcion:

```
$("#btnCheckout").click(function(){ 

    var total = $(".valorTotalCompra").html();
    var envio = $(".valorTotalEnvio").html();
    var subtotal = $(".valorSubtotal").html();
    var titulo = $(".valorTitulo");
    var cantidad = $(".valorCantidad");
    var valorItem = $(".valorItem");
    var idProducto = $('.cuerpoCarrito button, .comprarAhora button');

    var tituloArray = [];
    var cantidadArray = [];
    var valorItemArray = [];
    var idProductoArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < (titulo.length/2); i++){

        tituloArray[i] = $(titulo[i]).html();
        cantidadArray[i] = $(cantidad[i]).html();
        valorItemArray[i] = $(valorItem[i]).html();
        idProductoArray[i] = $(idProducto[i]).attr("idProducto");

    }

    var arrayFinal = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < (tituloArray.length); i++){

        arrayFinal[i] = {'titulo' : tituloArray[i], 'cantidad' : cantidadArray[i], 'valorItem' : valorItemArray[i], 'idProducto' : idProductoArray[i]}

    }

})
```

Quiero enviarlo mediante AJAX a mi archivo PHP haciendo lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({

     url:rutaOculta+"controladores/carrito.controlador.php",
     method:"POST",
     data: {'arrayFinal' : arrayFinal },
     success:function(respuesta){ 
     }

});
```

Luego en el archivo PHP intento acceder al array enviado por AJAX:

```
$array = $_POST['arrayFinal'];
var_dump($array);
```

Pero el navegador me dice esto:

> Notice: Undefined index: arrayFinal in...

Al hacer un print_r($_POST) dentro dentro esta clase del archivo PHP donde quiero usar el array:

```
class ControladorCompraEfectivoYTarjeta {

    public function ctrCompraEfectivo(){

        if(isset($_POST["registroUsuario"])){

          //aquí hay un if con validaciones de los campos que aparecen luego en el print_r

          print_r($_POST); 

       }

   }

}
```

Me muestra el print_r con datos de otros inputs de un formulario, pero no llega mi array:

> Array ( [registroUsuario] => Mariano Juan [registroDireccion] => San
>   Juan 2000, Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina [registroDireccion2] =>
>   [registroCalendario] => 19/12/2018 [registroHora] => [registroEmail]
>   => mariano@gmail.com [registroTelefono] => 3130888 )

**¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Ya intente mil maneras de poder acceder al array y no encentro solución.**

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86875/discussion-on-question-by-damian-ricobelli-como-hacer-para-enviar-correctamente).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con  `JSON.stringify(arrayFinal)` para pasar un array javascript a php, y en php usa `$array=json_decode($_POST['arrayFinal'])`; y listo ya tienes tu `$array` javascript en php

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas opciones, la del input en el form puede ser una, de todas formas tendras que usar JSON.stringify y al final en php json_decode, lo extraño es por que te aparece indefinido, tal vez deberias ponerle esta otra linea al ajax:

```
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

así aseguras que lo que envias es un json, saludos.